# I have tried everything but my pack_forget does not work in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know why but .pack_forget() is not working. Here is the code.

```
def home():
    home = Frame(root)
    welcome = Label(home, text = 'Welcome!')

    if btn.config('relief')[-1] == 'raised':
        btn.config(relief="sunken")
        home.pack() 
        welcome.pack()
    else:
        btn.config(relief="raised")
        home.pack_forget()
        welcome.pack_forget()
```

```
btn = Button(assignmentButtons, text = 'Home', borderwidth = 0, padx = 18, anchor = 'w', activebackground = '#4a4646', activeforeground = '#918787',  relief = RAISED, cursor = 'hand2', command = home)
btn.config(width=25, height=2, bg = '#363333', fg = '#918787')
btn.pack(anchor = 'nw')
```

Comment: Could you please include a complete compilable example?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is one of scope. `.pack_forget()` *is* removing the `home` frame and the `welcome` label from view. But the widgets that are being forgotten were only just created and never `.pack`'ed in the first place!

Every time your `btn` is pressed, a new frame named `home` and a new label called `welcome` are created. If `btn`'s relief value is `"raised"`, then these widgets are packed. Otherwise, the freshly created, not yet packed widgets are forgotten (which does nothing because they are not yet visible). You are never actually referring to the already packed widgets. You need to pass a reference to the widgets that were packed in order to remove them.

One way to do this is to generate your tkinter code using a class with `home` and `welcome` as attributes of the instantiated class. Then you can reference them with `self.home.pack_forget()` and `self.welcome.pack_forget()`.

See [this link](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-hide-recover-and-delete-tkinter-widgets/) for an example using a class definition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are running into is that you have a function and a TK Frame named the same thing. Try to differentiate them and see if that helps. ie. You have "home" listed as both the function and the Frame attached to root